# SMF Error: SMF could not connect to the database

Tags: php, cakephp-1.3, smf

I have a website built in CakePHP and I am using SMF as forum. I have kept the forum folder in webroot. Forum is fetching user session from cakephp and autologins the user into the forum. Forum tables are kept in same database. Whenever a user registers, entry is made into SMF members table.

I am getting emails containing this error message:

"There has been a problem with the database!

This is a notice email to let you know that SMF could not connect to the database, contact your host if this continues. "

The database connection is correct. Currently I have only 2 users in members table out of which one is forum administrator.

I have searched on internet but none of the solution works for me. I have been stuck with this issue for around two weeks.

I changed the whole database to innoDB when hosting server sent a ticket containing forum queries which were in 'waiting for table lock' state but it is giving same error again.

The ticket showed around 20 database connections open at a time.

Please advise.

Comment: Maybe at a certain moment the max db connections number gets exhausted from too many connections?

Comment: @BorislavSabev Yes, SMF opens up around 25 connections at a time. Thanks for the comment. Have to remove SMF.